# Docker and POSTGRESQL

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, django-postgresql

I create new project using Docker on Django. when I write settings to connect to Postgres it has some Error - (conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Thats my code in project :
settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:

      - db


  db:

      image: postgres:11
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: "db"
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
```

and Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7
# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code
# Install dependencies

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
# Copy project
COPY . /code/
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Please help to decide this problem.I read a lot information on stackoverflow about it.Changed code.But nothing to help me in this situation.

Comment: Check out name in DATABASES settings

Answer (score -1):

You must specify the hostname in:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

Otherwise it will try to connect to host with the name db.